# Aligning two divs vertically in responsive design

Tags: html, alignment

I'm trying to vertically align two divs in responsive design. One div contains an image and the other contains text. I want them to keep aligned for almost all large screen sizes.
The heights of both divs must be same on almost all large screens.

here is the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bangash/4cLQa/

and the html and css is given below.

```
CSS goes here
.box { float: left; font-size:15px;font-family:'fsl'; }
#main { width: 100%; }
#intro { width: 67%;}
#box-inside1{margin-top:2em;margin-left:2em;}
#slider-small { width: 33%; float:right;position: relative; padding:0; margin:0; }
#left { width: 50%;margin-right:4em;padding-bottom:3px;min-height:256px; }
#right { width: 40%;}
```

and the HTML goes here

```
<div class="box" id="main">
<div class="box" id="intro" style="background-color:#eae7e7;">
<div class="box" id="box-inside1">
<h3>IOC OFFICE 600SQM (EPC PROJECT)</h3>
Lead times:
<ul>
<li>Design &ndash; 4 weeks</li>
<li>Procure &ndash; 10 weeks</li>
<li>Construct (Shell and Core) &ndash; 16 weeks</li>
<li>Fit and Furnish &ndash; 16 weeks</li>
</ul>
Components:
<ul>
<li>Pre-fabricated steel structure</li>
<li>300 sqm - Two Levels</li>
<li>Overhead Protection of ground floor</li>
<li>100% local contractors for civil works, construction, fit &amp; furnish</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="dl-text">Download floor plan <span id="dl-icon">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="slider-small"><img src="http://atom.norseone.com/wb/media/property/case/1.jpg" width="100%" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me out.
Thanks

Comment: They are aligned. What's your problem?

Comment: resize the browser and see image is resizing but the height of the box is fixed. I want them to align in same height when resizing the browser screen.

Comment: Won't this distort your image? Not sure this is a good idea. Why not put the image on top of the description on smaller screen size, and have the image keep the same width as the description container?

Comment: On smaller screen sizes the image goes under the description. no issues with mobile view. Just facing problems with different screen resolutions of PCs

Answer (score 1):

```
height: 50vw;
```

or

```
height: 50vh;
```

These should be responsive, but try both of them out, as they will do different things. I'm sure one of them is what you are looking for.

Comment: That worked on my screen but when I checked it on others they had the same problem :(